# Update multiple JSON data into MySQL in php

Tags: php, mysql, json

I'm making a php for update multiple record. I try to print the posted JSON data but fail and it said I got a parse error. How to solve it?

Sorry I'm new in php, I think the code I wrote have many problem.

updateAccountbook.php

```
require("../db/MySQLDAO.php");

$config = parse_ini_file('../conn.ini');

$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$obj = json_decode($json, true);

echo $obj;
print_r($obj);

$dbhost = trim($config["dbhost"]);
$dbuser = trim($config["dbuser"]);
$dbpass = trim($config["dbpass"]);
$dbname = trim($config["dbname"]);

$dao = new MySQLDAO($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

$dao->openConnection();

$foreach($obj as $item) {
   mysql_query("INSERT INTO account_book (book_cid, book_name, book_type, book_category, book_user) 
   VALUES ('".$item['book_cid']."','".$item['book_name']."', '".$item['book_type']."', '".$item['book_category']."', '".$item['book_user']."')");

 }

$dao->closeConnection();

echo json_encode($returnValue);
```

mySQLDAO.php

```
class MySQLDAO{

var $dbhost = null;
var $dbuser = null;
var $dbpass = null;
var $conn = null;
var $dbname = null;
var $result = null;

function __construct($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpassword, $dbname) {
    $this->dbhost = $dbhost;
    $this->dbuser = $dbuser;
    $this->dbpass = $dbpassword;
    $this->dbname = $dbname;
} 


public function openConnection() { 
    $this->conn = new mysqli($this->dbhost, $this->dbuser, $this->dbpass, $this->dbname);
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
        throw new Exception("Could not establish connection with database");
    $this->conn->set_charset("utf8");
}

public function closeConnection() {
    if ($this->conn != null)
        $this->conn->close();
}

}
```

JSON Format

```
{
    "book_cid": "1234",
    "book_name" : "Test",
    "book_type": "Test",
    "book_category": "Test",
    "book_user": "Test"
}
```

Error message

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace

```
$foreach($obj as $item)
```

with

```
foreach($obj as $item)
```

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code is problematic:

```
$foreach($obj as $item){
mysql_query("INSERT INTO account_book (book_cid, book_name, book_type, book_category, book_user) VALUES ('".$item['book_cid']."','".$item['book_name']."', '".$item['book_type']."', '".$item['book_category']."', '".$item['book_user']."')");
}
```

You don't need a `foreach` loop to loop through one object. In this case drop the `foreach` and instead of `$item` write `$obj`:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO account_book (book_cid, book_name, book_type, book_category, book_user) VALUES ('".$obj['book_cid']."','".$obj['book_name']."', '".$obj['book_type']."', '".$obj['book_category']."', '".$obj['book_user']."')");
```

In case `$obj` has many rows of objects :

```
for($i=0; $i < count($obj); $i++)
{
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO account_book (book_cid, book_name, book_type, book_category, book_user) VALUES ('".$obj[$i]['book_cid']."','".$obj[$i]['book_name']."', '".$obj[$i]['book_type']."', '".$obj[$i]['book_category']."', '".$obj[$i]['book_user']."')");
}
```